# How to enable localhost access for other devices?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7, website

I have created an IIS website running on localhost:4401.
It opens without any problem on the system that I have the website on. Now I want to access this website from Android/Mac/Linux devices. I have a Wi-Fi connection that is connected to all the devices where I want to see the website on. Now the question is, how do I do this? I have created inbound access for port 4401 as a rule in Windows firewall. I have also modified the hosts file for my IP:
xxx.xxx.x.xxx                 webroot.dev
I don't have any internet connection on the network, it's a local network. How do I get it running and accessible from other devices and how do I change the default IIS page, to the one I want at localhost:80?

Comment: Am I on the right forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to the *local loopback* interface i.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`  from any other device. Therefore, you need to

- use the LAN IP of the server to connect.
- have the IIS bind to the network interface of your LAN. This should be the default, but you can debug this by using that IP instead of `localhost` on the machine itself.

You can modify the default site the same way you did with the additional site.

Comment: How do I bind IIS to the network interface?

Comment: [Add a Binding to a Site (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx)